# При изменении масштаба выпирает текст в UI QT

Tags: python, pyqt

Добавил элементы управления через Qt designer на форму `qwidget`. Все отлично смотрелось, пока не попробовал изменить масштаб в настройках *"Параметры экрана->Дисплей->Масштаб и разметка"*. Выглядит это так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В левой части часть интерфейса, в правой настройки масштаба. Использую Windows10, Pyhton 3.9, PyQt5. Как бороться со сдвигом текста в элементах?
**UDP:** Пример:

```
#main.py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from main_window import MainWindow

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
#main_window.py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QObject)
from ui_main_window import Ui_MainForm

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_MainForm):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
#ui_main_window.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainForm(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainForm):
        MainForm.setObjectName("MainForm")
        MainForm.resize(205, 184)
        self.btn_generate_file = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainForm)
        self.btn_generate_file.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 101, 41))
        self.btn_generate_file.setObjectName("btn_generate_file")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(MainForm)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 191, 91))
        self.groupBox.setTitle("")
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.btn_selected_groups = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.btn_selected_groups.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 81, 31))
        self.btn_selected_groups.setObjectName("btn_selected_groups")
        self.btn_unselected_groups = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.btn_unselected_groups.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 40, 81, 31))
        self.btn_unselected_groups.setObjectName("btn_unselected_groups")

        self.retranslateUi(MainForm)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainForm)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainForm):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainForm.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainForm", "Loader"))
        self.btn_generate_file.setText(_translate("MainForm", "Продолжить"))
        self.btn_selected_groups.setText(_translate("MainForm", "Выбрать все"))
        self.btn_unselected_groups.setText(_translate("MainForm", "Снять все"))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick Пример выложил

Comment: @helldrg, а если убрать использование `setFixedSize`?

Comment: @gil9red попробовал, все равно слова за границу выезжают

Comment: @helldrg, только что заметил, что вы не разместили виджеты в компоновщики (Q*Layout). Думаю, если вы поместите на компоновщики и не будете фиксировать размер окна, то размер виджетов будет подобран под размер шрифта системы

Comment: @gil9red Вы правильно говорите, добавить элементы на слой и убрать `self.setFixedSize(self.size())`. Возникает вопрос, а как тогда сделать, что бы форму нельзя было изменять в размерах?

Comment: Используйте все-же setFixedSize, просто задайте достаточно ширины в окне

Comment: @gil9red потестил сейчас один раз только вывело правильно, остальные разы выходило за рамки